# Is it possible to avoid setting project_id explicitly when authing with service account?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I'm trying to authenticate in a bash script and enable my service account and I have `cred.json`. Here is what I tried:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/etc/gcp-cred.json
```

The problem is that I have to set project explicitly:

```
gcloud config set project my_proj
```

Which is kind of redundant because `gcp-cred.json` contains this project already as a field:

```
"project_id": "my_proj"
```

Is there a way to avoid doing `gcloud config set project` explicitly and set it with `gcp-cred.json`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No -- `gcloud` will not change your working core project when authenticating.

The trick here is that authenticating & setting your "default" working project for `gcloud` are separate concerns.  You can set your project without authenticating, and you can authenticate without changing your project.

The logic here stems from the fact that an identity can have access to *many* projects.  Even though a Service Account is *homed* to a particular project, it could very well be authorized to access any other project.  So, the `gcloud` program makes no assumptions about which project you want your Service Account to act on.

Secondarily, in general you do not *have to* set your default working project for `gcloud` -- you can specify the project that is the target of your action with the flag `--project PROJECT_ID`.  See docs for that `gcloud` flag [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--project).

Comment: But since service account is tightly coupled to a particular project would it be safe to extract it manually just as parsing json?

Comment: @SomeName - A service account in one project can be used in another project. You can also create a service account that cannot be used in the same project. The CLI supports switching service accounts, so automatically changing the default Project ID is not necessarily a good idea. The service accounts `project_id` key only means that project the service account was created in and has little to do with which projects the service account is authorized for.

Comment: Right - I wouldn't stress a Service Account as "coupled" to a project.  Even though a Service Account was created in a project, it still may have 0 access to anything in that project!  IAM is a separate concern from where a Service Account was birthed.